# Get all roles from security database in Marklgoic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am trying the get roles from security database but i am not able to get all roles, it seems that Compartment   role i am not getting, below is the query i am trying.

```
for  $ids in xdmp:get-current-roles()
let $Rolename := xdmp:role-name($ids)
return $Rolename
```

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this, I want to get all the roles within security database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`xdmp:get-current-roles()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-current-roles) will only return the roles assigned and inherited by the current user.

In order to list all roles in the Security DB, use [`xdmp:roles()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:roles)

```
for  $ids in xdmp:roles()
let $Rolename := xdmp:role-name($ids)
return $Rolename
```